# Footer using Avada Theme in Wordpress and the Polylang Plug-In

Tags: css, wordpress, widget, footer

I am currently using the Avada Theme. I want to create a multilingual site - for that I installed the Plugin called "Polylang". I want to have two sites - one in English, and one in German. Unfortunately with this plugin the Avada theme does not show the footer that is set in the layout options in the theme for the German version of my site.

I also tried to use the WordPress Footer widgets, but with those I was not able to display my footer as I wanted to. But maybe there is a simple solution with the footer widgets.

I want to display the footer like that - simple as that:

[image: Footer Required]

The texts are linking to different site. Does anyone got a solution?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This caught me out too.

In the same way that Polylang gives you options to add different language versions of a post, it also gives you the same options within Avada layouts.

Go to the Avada Layouts Builder page. Pick a custom layout section (e.g. Footer). Edit that and you'll find the same language options on the right.

Copy the basic text of your EN layout code. Hit the plus for German. Copy your text. Name it Footer DE or something, tweak it as required, and it should solve the problem.